# Which rules, spells or abilities - if any - can be used in 5E that dictate sanguimancy for PCs or hire?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic

Which skills, spells and abilities can be achieved with dragon's blood in 5E beyond directly damaging or locating the creature? I am looking for both homebrew and as-written rules, spells or abilities.

In addtion, are there any good 5th edition or homebrew consequences for using blood magic? In my campaign the act of blood magic is inherently evil.

Backstory:

So I tricked my players into releasing an imprisoned shadow dragon which they thought was a silver dragon. It immediately went and destroyed a nearby city and I had lot's of fun getting them to hate and want to kill this creature to try and redeem themselves.

During the session they were able to get a hold of some of the dragons blood in the form of they scooped about 2 kg (4.5 lbs) of dirt that it's blood had soaked into. They really want to separate the blood from the dirt and use it for some pretty sinister magic to hurt the dragon.

The obvious things they could do with it is locating the dragon/straight up damage. What are some creative things they could do that are a little outside the box that I could have an NPC suggest that would be more fun and interesting?